# Does $A^2$ similar to $B^2$ imply that $A$ is similar to $B$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So we have square matrices $A$ and $B$. Now suppose $A^2$ and $B^2$ are similar, does it follow that $A$ and $B$ are similar?
I don't think so, but I'm having trouble showing is not.

***My attempt:***
*If $A$ is similar to $B$, and $A$ is similar to $C$, then $B$ is also similar to C. More importantly, $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix of its eigenvalues, then $B$ must also be. So $A$ and $B$ have the same eigen values. But then I realised that this question doesn't even make the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are invertible, so they may or may not have those eigen values.*

Can someone give me some hints to this question?
If this is a proof by counterexample, is there at least some way to narrow the possible contradictions down by some theorem?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You can assume that $A$ and $B$ are diagonal.

Comment: And $1 \times 1$. :)

Comment: If you were proving this (were it true) certainly it would be insufficient to assume the matrices are diagonal. However, what you really mean is that it's not true and one can find a diagonal counterexample.

Comment: @MattSamuel that's too much of a hint.